# I'm looking for links to cdb/windbg + .net documentation

Tags: c#, windbg, sos

I just started using cdb and I love it!

I've found and [bookmarked](http://delicious.com/john.weldon/cdb) a few interesting articles I've found on using cdb, but I'd  love to see other peoples resources.

What sites do you use to extract the max usefulness from cdb (windbg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code project has a great beginners article on WinDbg.  There may be some items you have not seen yet.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx

Here is a list of some commonly used features

http://www.windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html

Answer (score 3):

This is a great book: [Advanced Windows Debugging](http://advancedwindowsdebugging.com/), though it is more focused on Native than Managed debugging.  It has some links that may be interesting to you.

Comment: Great answer too, I'm sorry I can only choose one accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a series of links that I have collected on WinDbg/SOS over the years:

- [If broken it is fix it you should blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20100219233135/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/tess/default.aspx) -- Tess Ferrandez's excellent blog on WinDbg/.Net debugging with interesting [labs](https://web.archive.org/web/20100118142529/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/tess/pages/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx)
- [WinDbg / SOS Cheat Sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024041713/http://geekswithblogs.net/.NETonMyMind/archive/2006/03/14/72262.aspx) -- Commonly used SOS commands
- [John Robbin's Blog / CmdTree information](https://web.archive.org/web/20100323134731/http://www.wintellect.com:80/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2008/09/17/windbg-cmdtree-file-that-eases-some-sos-pain.aspx) -- CmdTree is a hidden feature of WinDbg to create shortcuts to commonly used items
- [SOSEX](https://web.archive.org/web/20220605125636/http://www.stevestechspot.com/) -- Steve Johnson's SOS Extensions that contain a bunch of exta .Net debugging extensions

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954594.aspx) is a good series of articles about .NET debugging from the MSDN library, it covers using WinDbg and Core Debugger.